# google chrome display content fuzzy and blurred

Tags: jquery, css

recently i run through a strange problem,
i'm creating a modal but when i show the modal using javascript ( jQuery ) it appear blurred in google chrome while looks fine in firefox and Microsoft edge.

this is my styling for the modal ( sass3 & Bourbon )

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    cursor: pointer;

    @include position( fixed, 0 0 0 0 );
    z-index: 666;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    background-color: $white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid shade($th-light-bgcolor, 10%);
    border-radius: 5px;

    @include position( fixed, 50% null null 50% );
    @include transform( translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%));
    z-index: 999;
}
```

jQuery

```
target.css({ top: "48%", opacity: 0 }).show().animate({ "top": "50%", opacity: 1 });
```

and this is how it's look in google chrome 
[image]

**the image is blurred too !**

i tried to isolate the problem by trying to find any code conflict and i found that this block cause the problem

```
@include keyframes(spin-1) {
  from {
    @include transform(rotate(0deg));
  }
  to {
    @include transform(rotate(360deg));
  }
}
```

every think become fine when i remove it !
any clue ?

here is a live demo : [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyPQmX) 
* see that the spinner and the modal never work together

Comment: Not sure, but if it's just the text, try -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; Without seeing a live version, it's hard to debug. But from the looks, I can't see an obvious reason for the blur.

Comment: not the text only every thing is blurred ( text / image / border ), i tried this property too but didn't work .

Comment: Hmm, is there a working version, I can take a look.

Comment: Not sure if it'll be much help but you could try adding in [PrefixFree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js)

Comment: it's become stranger now, i update the problem cause

Comment: a demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyPQmX see that the spinner and the modal never works together